# (Bootstrap) Как выровнять блок по центру?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image]

Имеются вот такие вот блоки, но меня раздражает этот отступ справа. Что можно предпринять?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал этот способ. В моём случае он нерабочий.

Comment: То покажите Ваш случай, мы же не знаем что у ВАС там

Comment: Сейчас покажу, что у меня за случай

Comment: если по 3 блока в ряд по центру, то в одном row , три блока col-md-4

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 somebody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="../img/no-avatar.png"></div>
                        <div class="col">
                                <a class="name">Somebodiest Somebody</a><br>
                                <a class="work">Bringing coffee</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Чёрт возьми, это работает! Весь контент с этими блоками выровнилось ровно по центру, как я и хотел! Огромное спасибо вам!

Comment: @Endivine Пожалуйста